# Как выйти на новый уровень в разработке C#

Tags: c#

Может я немного не туда пишу, но все же. Я учусь на 3 курсе универа, учат так себе, куча ненужных предметов было, впрочем как и везде наверное. Так вот, знаю основы c#, запросы sql server изучали, что делать дальше? Как упорядочить знания и научиться выполнять норм. задания.

При виде заданий такого типа ступор(это в платной стажировке, а у меня практика только в конце 3 курса(всего курсов - 4)):

- выгрузить из БД в Excel список сотрудников указанного подразделения с доступными для них маршрутами передвижения
- обновить маршруты передвижения в БД
- создать систему выдачи разовых пропусков (подача заявки, подтверждение, согласование, внесение данных в БД, формирование разового пропуска)
- и т.д.

Я ничего не знаю будто, разве что основы, как быть, что делать. 
В феврале планирую пойти на стажировку другую(вроде как неоплачиваемую, мб там задания легче), но хочется научиться выполнять сложные вещи, такие как выше. А в моем универе(Я не в Москве/Питере, если там конечно круто учат) этому не учат.

Нравится

Comment: Все что я могу сказать - нужна практика. Чтобы делать сложные штуки, нужно уметь делать штуки попроще. Сделай приложение с CRUD операциями, как поймешь - двигайся дальше.

Comment: Я согласен с Шамилем: нужна практика. Начинайте с первой части первого пункта: "Выгрузить из БД". Создайте проект любого типа (консольное приложение пойдёт), подключайтесь к БД и выбирайте данные; вывести для начала можно просто в консоль. Что-то не получается - приходите сюда (или на любой другой форум) и задавайте _конкретный_ вопрос с описанием, что сделано и что не получилось. Потом переходите к следующему пункту и т. д.

Comment: _куча ненужных предметов было_ - ох, как ошибаетесь. Все предметы нужны, просто вы пока этого не понимаете.

Comment: Основной принцип для выполнения подобных заданий - это делить сложное задание на набор меньших заданий попроще, потом каждое задание попроще делить на набор совсем простых заданий. И вот у тебя уже не одна непонятная задача, а куча мелких простых задач, которые надо просто сесть и сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Выйти на новый уровень С#, можно либо постоянно им занимаясь, а  можно поверить, что все знаете и выйти на "новый" уровень, который не всегда будет выше текущего. Даже практики как таковой недостаточно, так как нужно стремление разобраться. Наверное это главное.

По задаче:**1**

1.0

Вам нужно скачать любой workbench, для того чтобы открыть и посмотреть содержимое БД.

1.1

Если вам предоставили готовую БД. Вам нужно искать таблицу похожую на (Employee,Person, ...) для нахождения сотрудника в этой таблице должна быть ссылка на таблицу (Role,Unit,Subdivision,...) далее смотреть есть ли таблица похожая на (Route,...) или это просто поле в (Role,Unit,Subdivision,...) и.т.д

1.2

Если БД нет, то смотрите примеры по созданию БД, в той среде разработки которую скачали в пункте 1.0. Создавайте максимально примитивную модель данных и заполняйте любым способом.

1.3

Дальше создайте любой новый проект и попытайтесь в коде получить любое поле из БД. Далее повторить это с нужной таблицей, на результат от вас ждут либо таблицу, либо набор таблиц!

**2**.
 Под словом "обновить" может пониматься команда из языка SQL "Update", если это "поле", то простая его замена. Вам нужна таблица (Route,...).

**3** .
 Возможно от вас хотят модуль с Gui. Где на форме есть текст бокс в который должна вписаться заявка, фактически тут вам нужно по событиям с кнопок "Подтверждения" и "Согласование" вернуть их результаты поля объекта, ну например

```
`public class Order
    {
        Employee person {get;set;}
        bool Confirm { get; set; }
        bool Matching { get; set; }
        string Text { get; set; }
    }`)
```

Сохранить это в БД. Причем скорее всего нужно завязать это на таблицу "Роли", где кто-то может "Подтверждать", а кто-то "Согласовывать").

```
       public class Pass
    {
        bool OneOff { get; set; }
        Order GetOrder()
        {
            return new Order(Employee employee)
            {
                Confirm = false,//результат с GUI
                Matching = false,//результат с GUI
                Text = textBox.Text//результат с GUI
            };
        }            
    }
```

Опять же, если БД имеется, скорее всего требуется использовать таблицы от туда.